# Google apps script get user input with no length limit

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to take user input (HTML specifically) using either:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Paste HTML below');
```

or

```
var input = Browser.inputBox('Paste HTML below', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
```

**These work fine for small inputs, however when copying over the entire HTML for a page of interest an error occurs (in each case). This error cannot be caught, it simply crashes the script.**

Do you know why this is happening? I can't find anything in the docs that mention limits on input size.

Any experience doing this a different way?

*Edit: as per a suggestion in the comments, I have tried another method (below). This also fails (with no error message) when passed large input.*

First I set up `Page.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Paste Sitemap Content Below
    <textarea id="user-input-box" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <script>
      function logToConsole() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input-box").value;
        google.script.run.doSomething(userInput);
      }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="logToConsole();google.script.host.close();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in file `Code.gs`

```
function testDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}

function doSomething(userInput){
  Logger.log(userInput);
}
```

Comment: Using a [Google Form](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) seems a natural solution, the form can have a large box for text entry and invoke the script on submission (on Form Submit trigger)

Comment: Use a custom dialog:  [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) With text area:  [textarea information](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Comment: @SandyGood Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like the custom dialog you linked me to uses `ui.prompt `, which I have already experimented with. @Michelle I was hoping to do this entirely inside the sheets app for this project but that's very good to know. Thank you both for the suggestions

Comment: You need to look at the "Page.html" tab in the documentation.  You have *not* used the code in that example.  That documentation does not use `ui.prompt`  Unfortunately, the graphic in that documentation is misleading.  Read the documentation.  You haven't read it.

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks for the details (and reminding me that I did not read the docs... I can be so forgetful). I understand what you are getting at now. To send the data back to the script I found [this resource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and couldn't log the error. In my case as is yours, you're calling your logToConsole() function and then directly after you're closing the dialog by using google.script.host.close();

google.script.host.close() is the problem. For some reason it can cancel the script execution - this typically happens when you're sending a lot of data back. The trick is to use a successHandler when you call your script which then calls google.script.host.close(). This way, the data transfer from the dialog finishes correctly and when you call withSuccessHandler(), that callback closes the dialog. Try this amendment to your code:

```
<script>
    function logToConsole() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input-box").value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeDialog).doSomething(userInput);
    }

    function closeDialog() {
        google.script.host.close();
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="logToConsole()" />
```